# Refresh environment variables for open VS solution

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Using visual studio 2008, I had a solution open and realized I need to install another program that the project I was working on used. I did this with visual studio open and attempted to debug the program, however the environment variables added by the program I installed were not visible. I could not get them to refresh until I exited VS and reloaded the solution. Is there a way to get visual studio to "refresh" its environment variable list without exiting and reloading the solution?

As an additional note, I did use [process explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to look at the environment variables for the application and could confirm that it was not aware of the environment variable I needed.

Comment: Here's a handy idea to use *.h files - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22503430/set-preprocessor-definitions-from-file-content-in-visual-c

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Nope.  Environment variable changes on Windows only take effect for new processes.  You'll have to exit Visual Studio and restart it.

Comment: Need trigger in launch.json to always re-read environment variables on start. My use is reset of a paper-trading account (new keys each time).

Comment: Is this still true for VS 2017 and later?

Comment: @lit: Yes it is, I just tested it on VS2019.

Comment: As of VS 2022 I had a situation where even a restart of the computer didn't clear the environment variables set in local.settings.json on a Functions App project. Deleting the obj folder was the only remedy.  Probably due to the startup "optimizations" in the latest builds? Citing someone more clever than me: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil" ;)

Comment: I added an answer now. You can get the environment variable if you use Chocolatey's :
refreshenv
in a terminal window inside VS.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's any way round this. You have to restart the VS process so it can pick up the changes to the environment.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very old question, but it is still something VS users probably want to do without closing down the entire VS process.

You can get the environment variables without restarting VS 2022 process if you open up a terminal and with the help of this Chocolatey command:

```
refreshenv
```

Obviously, this requires that you have installed Chocolatey on your system.

Please note that if you have added environment variable as a system variable, set also the EnvironmentVariableTarget to Machine. Example :

```
string uri = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_COGNITIVE_SERVICE_ENDPOINT", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine);
```

Comment: This works in the terminal window but not when debugging an asp.net core process

Comment: Well, that probably depends on which IConfiguation you are using. Often you have to restart the asp.net core process if you do not use IOptionsMonitor or similar since a snapshot of the appsettings file was read at startup and later changes does not catch the changes to appsettings file.