# Set preprocessor definitions from file content in Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, c-preprocessor

I have a file in my project which contains the project version number. I have to make the content of this file available as a preprocessor definition in my code.

What I need is to somehow pass the value from the file to the compiler as a /D parameter.

I tried to add the preprocessor definition

```
VERSION=$(Version)
```

and set the Version environment variable in a prebuild step, but I did not find a way to do the latter, so I got stuck.

Comment: Auto-generating a .h file with a #define that you #include in a .cpp or .rc file is the simple and boilerplate solution.  Controlling a /D compiler option might be possible, depends a lot on how you build, rarely very practical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a workaround, a pre-build step could be created which calls a script that reads the file and generates the macro definition in a header. Then this header file could be included in my projects.

However I do not find this solution nice, I hope there is a better one.

Comment: This is actually how one of my projects deals with versioning. As a prebuild step, it gets a version number from Mercurial and writes a corresponding `#define` into a header file. The header is included in my project, so the freshly-generated version number is available to me without any extra work required.

Comment: I accepted this based on current votes and comments but I hope someone will come up with a more accurate solution.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to generating .h files, you can also generate a .vsprops (Property Sheet) file. .vsprops files are to .vcproj files what .h files are to .cpp files. In particular, you can define a `/D` command-line option in a property sheet. This is how `/D UNICODE` is commonly define, via a default property sheet.

The additional benefit is that you can also set the `/VERSION` flag for the linker, something which you can't do via a header file.