# How do I pass command line parameters to a test in visual studio when executing tests from test explorer?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, command-line-arguments

I want to be able to run tests from test explorer within visual studio by passing command-line arguments. I want to do this in order to be able to debug tests by setting breakpoints, which is easier for me to debug visually.

Currently, this is how I run tests from command-line:

```
PS> $env Browsestack_automation='false'; dotnet test
```

How can I achieve this?

---

@Jonathan Dodds, this is the .runsettings file that I've added to the root of my project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
  <!-- Configurations that affect the Test Framework -->
  <RunConfiguration>
    <!-- Use 0 for maximum process-level parallelization. This does not force parallelization within the test DLL (on the thread-level). You can also change it from the Test menu; choose "Run tests in parallel". Unchecked = 1 (only 1), checked = 0 (max). -->
    <MaxCpuCount>0</MaxCpuCount>
    <!-- Path relative to directory that contains .runsettings file-->
    <ResultsDirectory>.\TestResults</ResultsDirectory>

    <!-- Omit the whole tag for auto-detection. -->
    <!-- [x86] or x64, ARM, ARM64, s390x  -->
    <!-- You can also change it from the Test menu; choose "Processor Architecture for AnyCPU Projects" -->
    <!-- TargetPlatform>x86</TargetPlatform -->

    <!-- Any TargetFramework moniker or omit the whole tag for auto-detection. -->
    <!-- net48, [net40], net6.0, net5.0, netcoreapp3.1, uap10.0 etc. -->
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>net7.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>

    <!-- Path to Test Adapters -->
    <!-- TestAdaptersPaths>%SystemDrive%\Temp\foo;%SystemDrive%\Temp\bar</TestAdaptersPaths -->

    <!-- TestCaseFilter expression -->
    <!-- TestCaseFilter>(TestCategory == BrowserStack)</TestCaseFilter -->

    <!-- TestSessionTimeout was introduced in Visual Studio 2017 version 15.5 -->
    <!-- Specify timeout in milliseconds. A valid value should be greater than 0 -->
    <TestSessionTimeout>10000</TestSessionTimeout>

    <!-- true or false -->
    <!-- Value that specifies the exit code when no tests are discovered -->
    <TreatNoTestsAsError>true</TreatNoTestsAsError>

    <EnvironmentVariables> 
        <!-- List of environment variables we want to set--> <BROWSERSTACK_AUTOMATION>false</BROWSERSTACK_AUTOMATION> 
    </EnvironmentVariables> 
  </RunConfiguration>
</RunSettings>
```

Comment: Unit Tests don't have command-line parameters...

Comment: @Dai they do. In my example above, I can also suffix --filter 'Category'='@Sanity', if I have tests tagged as Sanity

Comment: You're conflating other kinds of automated tests (such as E2E tests and integration-tests) with unit-tests. The term "unit test" is not a synonym for "automated test". Unit tests are the smallest, simplest kind of test imaginable: they test the smallest unit of a program, such as a single function or method or similar (which is also why they don't need externally-exposed parameters) - whereas invoking `Browserstack` is the complete opposite: that's an E2E test.

Comment: I thought you're answering the question but you're just critical about the jargon. You're right about unit tests not having command-line parameters but your response still doesn't help my question in any way

Comment: No, it doesn't - but it is a hint that you should retitle your question so that it attracts someone who can answer your question ;)

Comment: @Sanu You are not passing command line parameters. You are using environment variables. In your command window, set your environment variables and then launch Visual Studio by running devenv.exe. To change your environment, close Visual Studio, change the environment, and relaunch.

Comment: @JonathanDodds Awesome! that worked, thanks. You saved me a lot of headache. You could've posted this as an answer and I'd have accepted it (You can still do). BTW 2 questions, if you can help further:

1. What does devenv.exe do? Can I not just open a new instance of Visual Studio manually?

2. How can I set the environment variables without restarting Visual Studio? I'm trying to run tests both on BrowserStack and Locally. I want to switch between them during runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example doesn't show passing command line parameters. It shows the use of environment variables.

In your command window, set your environment variables and then launch Visual Studio by running devenv.exe. To change your environment, close Visual Studio, change the environment, and relaunch.

devenv.exe is Visual Studio. (If you examine a start menu or taskbar shortcut you will see a path that ends with `devenv.exe`.)

When devenv.exe is started in the command prompt, it gets the current set of environment variables. After the devenv process is started, changing the variables in the command prompt process (or in Windows Settings) will have no effect.

### Changing the Environment for a Test Run

Take a look at creating a [.runsettings file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/configure-unit-tests-by-using-a-dot-runsettings-file?view=vs-2022). The Visual Studio Test Explorer is running a test runner. In the .runsettings file you can [specify environment variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/configure-unit-tests-by-using-a-dot-runsettings-file?view=vs-2022#specify-environment-variables-in-the-runsettings-file) that will be passed to the test runner when Test Explorer starts the test runner process.

You will need two .runsettings files: one for local and one for BrowserStack. In the "Test" menu in Visual Studio you will be able to switch between the two .runsettings files.

Comment: This didnt work. I added a .runsettings file in the root of my project with the following within it and when I run the tests from Test Explorer, it still runs the test in BrowserStack instead of my local machine:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- File name extension must be .runsettings -->
<RunSettings>
 <RunConfiguration>
  <EnvironmentVariables>
   <!-- List of environment variables we want to set-->
   <BROWSERSTACK_AUTOMATION>false</BROWSERSTACK_AUTOMATION>
  </EnvironmentVariables>
 </RunConfiguration>
</RunSettings>
I can also see this runsettings file under TEST

Comment: You are using Visual Studio 2022 and you followed the instructions about [creating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/configure-unit-tests-by-using-a-dot-runsettings-file?view=vs-2022#create-a-run-settings-file-and-customize-it) and [specifying](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/configure-unit-tests-by-using-a-dot-runsettings-file?view=vs-2022#specify-a-run-settings-file-in-the-ide) a *.runsettings file?

Comment: Also, you mentioned: After the devenv process is started, changing the variables in the command prompt process (or in Windows Settings) will have no effect.

However, this command sets the env variables without me restarting VS:
PS> $env Browserstack_automation='false'; dotnet test

Comment: yes I've done that. I've now edited the question with the .runsettings file that I've added.

Comment: `$env Browserstack_automation='false'; dotnet test` is running a new process instance of dotnet with a changed environment. This is unrelated to the Visual Studio process.

Comment: Ok. btw, do you think the .runsettings file looks ok? Wonder why its not working though

Comment: In terms of formatting, I don't see issues with the .runsettings file.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting Jonathan Dodds' comment:

This is because you are not passing command line arguments. You are using environment variables. In the command window, set the environment variables, and then start Visual Studio by running devenv.exe. To change the environment, close Visual Studio, change the environment, and then restart.

**1. What does devenv.exe do?**

Yes, devenv.exe allows you to open a new instance of Visual Studio

**2. How to set environment variables without restarting Visual Studio?**

Restarting Visual Studio is to make the set environment variables take effect.

In general, if you change environment variables after Visual Studio starts, those changes usually don't take effect immediately in the currently running instance of Visual Studio. Visual Studio reads system and user environment variables when it starts, but for an already running process, environment variables generally remain unchanged during its lifetime. Therefore, there is currently no direct method that does not require restarting Visual Studio. For details, please refer to: [Refresh environment variables for open VS solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120448/refresh-environment-variables-for-open-vs-solution)

Comment: devenv.exe **is** visual Studio.

Comment: This statement is incorrect: "In general, if you change environment variables after Visual Studio starts, those changes usually don't take effect immediately in the currently running instance of Visual Studio." A running process never sees environment variable changes made in either Windows Settings or in a "parent" process.